# Jsoup: Replace a tag with new line => new line begins with space

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have to replace several HTML tags with a new line, e.g. the p tag as you see in the example code:

```
String html = "<p>Zeile1</p><p>Zeile2</p><p>Zeile3</p><p>Zeile4</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.select("p").append("\\n");
String sanitized = doc.text().replaceAll("\\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator");
System.out.println(sanitized);
```

Here's the output:

```
Zeile1
 Zeile2
 Zeile3
 Zeile4
```

As you can see I get spaces in lines 2-4.
Where do they come from and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: the spaces are added between the `p` elements as soon as you call `text()` on the Document.  Not sure why.  You could get a collection of each text element and concatenate them to get rid of the spaces if there isn't a setting for it.

Answer (score 3):

Like @bdares suggestion, you can iterate through the elements:

```
String html = "<p>Zeile1</p><p>Zeile2</p><p>Zeile3</p><p>Zeile4</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for (Element p : doc.select("p")) {
    b.append(p.text());
    b.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
System.out.println(b.toString());
```

Output:

```
Zeile1
Zeile2
Zeile3
Zeile4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I used the String.trim()-method to clean up the spaces because I do not only replace the p tag but a few more like div,pre,br,h1-h6,...